# Cannot pass value to SalesForce from Docusign Document, SOAP API, MergeFieldXml

Tags: soap, salesforce, docusignapi

Good day everyone,

I need to pass the value of a write-back field from docusign document to Salesforce.

Can you kindly provide an example of a string specifying the properties of MergeFieldXml like configuration type, path,  etc.

According to Docusign SOAP API (https://www.docusign.net/api/3.0/dsapi.asmx?op=RequestEnvelopeWithDocumentFields) the MergeField property is passed as string:

```
<MergeFieldXml>string</MergeFieldXml>
```

At the same time the string should contain properties like:

Configuration type: salesforce (always)

path: objetc.field

row: record id

writeback: true if the data should be posted to salesforce.

My try does not work showing 'Web service callout failed: WebService returned a SOAP Fault: A Mergefield value for a Tab could not be retrieved. faultcode=soap:Client faultactor=missing in Web.Config
Row Number: 1196'

```
tab19.MergeFieldXml = '<configurationType>salesforce</configurationType><path>contact.Question_1_Agreement__c</path><writeback>true</writeback><allowSenderToEdit>false</allowSenderToEdit>';
```

If using REST API this would look as follows:

"mergeField": {
   "configurationType":"Salesforce",
   "path":"contact.Question_1_Agreement__c",
   "writeback":"true",
   "allowSenderToEdit":"true",
   }

According to SOAP API documentation (https://www.docusign.com/p/APIGuide/APIGuide.htm#Sending Group/Tab.htm%3FTocPath%3DDocuSign%2520Service%2520API%2520Information%7CSending%2520Function%2520Group%7CCreateAndSendEnvelope%2520and%2520CreateEnvelope%7CTab%7C_____0)

MergeFieldXml is 'reserved for future'.

Does it mean it is not implemented yet?

how do we pass values back to salesforce using SOAP MergeFieldXml?
Or there may be some other way to accomplish this?

Thank you for any advise.

Comment: Can you please format your question as per [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - it's hard to understand. Thanks.

Comment: Can you please check https://support.docusign.com/en/articles/DocuSign-for-Salesforce-INVALID-FIELD, https://support.docusign.com/guides/dfs-admin-guide-add-custom-tags-with-merge-field-settings-admin and https://support.docusign.com/guides/dfs-admin-guide-create-merge-fields-admin

Comment: I have checked this article earlier. This does not seem to be an issue. In the meantime i'm trying to accomplish this task using REST API. The call is performed successfully, however the value itself does not pass to salesforce.

Comment: This is how i expect the JSON for the mergeField to be generated:    
   gen.writeFieldName('mergeField');
   gen.writeStartObject();
   gen.writeObjectField('configurationType','salesforce');
   gen.writeObjectField('path','Contact.Question_1_Agreement__c');
   gen.writeObjectField('row','1');
   gen.writeObjectField('writeback','true');
   gen.writeObjectField('allowSenderToEdit','true');
   gen.writeEndObject();